# Storing queue in hash table or vector of vector

Tags: data-structures, hashmap, queue, client-server, server-side

I have a server-multiple client server - upon receiving a message from a client, the server needs to process it, before it gets passed on to another client.

I do not know what the best implementation is for what I would like to do, so would appreciate any help. These messages will be sent at time intervals, so the message needs to be received, processed, and pushed into a structure, before being accessed from the structure to be sent on at a certain time. The message has two attributes: destination and priority level. The access will be carried out at time intervals which has two modes: either specific to a client node, or open to all nodes for receiving.

1. If the time interval only allows a specific node to receive, what happens is all the queues are checked from highest priority to lowest i.e. the earliest message sent at the highest priority will be 'pushed' out from the structure.
2. If the time interval is 'open', then the earliest message of the highest priority regardless of node will be 'pushed' out.

I first thought that it could be a `vector<vector<queue<message>>`, but I realized that would not be efficient for searching according to point 2. I would appreciate any advice! I was advised about using a hash map, but I have no experience with this and would appreciate advice if this was the best way to go about it.

edit: Is a better solution to push the same message into two different structures? One: categorising according to priority level, vector holding FIFO queues (one for each priority level). Two: categorising it according to node, `vector<vector<queue<message>>`.

Comment: To clarify, is every message always destined for *one* node? Also, what's the likely number of nodes (at least a very rough range: tens, hundreds, thousands)?

Comment: @Darius The message will initially be destined for only one node (subsequently broadcasting might be implemented). The likely number of nodes will range from the tens-hundreds. Sorry for not making that clear!

Answer (score 1):

HThere's no one answer for this unless one has an idea of sizes and speeds. So, I figured I would put down some options that I came up with.

**Option 1 -- Super computer:** Suppose we assume a super fast machine, compared to the volume of data involved. We could simply store the messages in an unordered list, because it would be fast enough to run through the list each time (on average we would need to run through half the list).

**Option 1A -- Let's bother a little bit**: A list ordered by Priority+Time-of-arrival would make the "open" response fast, since we just take from the "top". For node-specific responses, we would typically search much less than half, because the top priorities are all near the beginning

**Option 2 -- Low resources, a hundred nodes, hundreds of messages:** If the insert-time into the data-structure is not so important, and you simply must have the shortest possible response when you need to send a message out, then you need a global queue so that you can pop when the interval is open. You also need node-specific queues. Finally you need a way to get to the node-specific queue instantateously. This implies:

1. Global ordered list
2. N node-specific ordered-list
3. Map keyed by Node-Id, and pointing to the node-specific list

As I see it, the painful part would be to synchronize so that you remove from both global and node-specific lists each time (the same while adding)

My first thought is to wrap each message in a wrapper that acts like a node in a doubly-linked list. However, it would actually be two lists. The wrapper would have a Prev and Next based on the Global priority; but, it would also have a Prev and Next based on the node-specific priority. That way you have only one copy of the message itself which you take out, while Fixing prev/next pointers in a standard way. (This basically combines #1 and #2 above).

For #3, I would keep a map, but instead of looking up a node-specific list, it would point to the "head" wrapper for that particular node.

Here's a picture, to illustrate.
[image: Double Duty, doubly-linked list]

It sounds like fun!